# Can we put regex in seleniumServerJar of exports.config of protractor

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Selenium server standalone jar version keeps updating and `webdriver-manager update` command picks latest jar. Every time selenium jar update I need to change seleniumServerJar in exports.config.

Is there any way to put some regex?

Like this :-

```
seleniumServerJar: "../node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-*.jar",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - ***No you cannot***. As per the implementation of protractor config parser, the `seleniumServerJar` property accepts only a `string` as its value. [Here's a link to its implementation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/configParser.js#L166). As you can see, until the `typeof` - `seleniumServerJar`'s value is `string`, protractor will not resolve the path of the jar file. And if the value is a string that doesn't resolve to a particular path in your directory, then protractor will throw an error.

**Edit:** Protractor tests will run even if you don't provide path of `seleniumServerJar` as its an `optional` property that you can provide if you store the jar file in a different location other than the default location. Default location here is either path where protractor is installed or relative path of your config file. Which means whether you install protractor locally or globally selenium server jar protractor executes your scripts.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any workaround you can suggest?

Comment: You can remove the property and try. Since its an optional property, you shouldn't face any errors(let me know if you are getting an error). Updated answer with the same. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked for the optional parameter :)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentions, if you simply remove `seleniumServerJar` from your config file, it will look for the jar file that is in `protractor/selenium` folder, which is where `webdriver-manager update` downloads to. Then you won't have to worry about bumping the version in your config file when you upgrade protractor since `webdriver-manager` gets the version number from `protractor/config.json`.

Relevant source documentation:

 `Priority
 1) if directConnect is true, use that
 2) if seleniumAddress is given, use that
 3) if a Sauce Labs account is given, use that
 4) if a seleniumServerJar is specified, use that
 5) try to find the seleniumServerJar in protractor/selenium`